# Problema em alinhar com responsividade

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Eu gostaria de alinhar o botão x no canto superior direito da imagem vide imagem e exemplo:

```css
.teste {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-teste {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-teste input[type=button] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: white;
  cursor: inherit;
  display: block;
}

.options {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 82px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<br/><br/>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 center-block text-center">
  <div class="options">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Remover"> 
   <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
  </button>
  </div>
  <span class="btn btn-default btn-teste">
  <img class="teste" width="100px" height="150px" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==" />
  <div> 
   Teste <input type="button" class="file">
  </div>
 </span>
</div>
```

Como gostaria que ficasse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema aqui é a responsividade, quando aumento ou diminuo a largura da tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou usar media queries do CSS para diferentes tamanhos de tela repassando diferentes margins?

Comment: A classe para o `button` com o `x` está correta ? Parece que o `css` que postou é relativo ao `Teste` ... Não deveria postar o código da classe `btn btn-default`?

Comment: btn, btn-default são classes padrões do bootstrap, não são relativas ao meu código @MagicHat

Comment: @AndréGava eu sou horrível com css, eu peguei desse exemplo e adaptei: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/RldKA, me parece que no caso desse exemplo não foi usado esse tipo de recurso (media queries), se puder fugir de escrever diversos tipos de classes pra cada tipo de tela, eu preferirira

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque o botão dentro do box da imagem, assim o `position:absolut` vai ser em relação a esse box e não o box externo que muda de tamanho, e assim você tem sempre a mesma posição.

veja abaixo:

```css
.teste {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.btn-teste {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-teste input[type=button] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  outline: none;
  background: white;
  cursor: inherit;
  display: block;
}

.options {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 12px;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<br/><br/>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 center-block text-center">
  <span class="btn btn-default btn-teste">
    <div class="options">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" title="Remover"> 
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  <img class="teste" width="100px" height="150px" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///ywAAAAAAQABAAACAUwAOw==" />
  <div> 
   Teste <input type="button" class="file">
  </div>
 </span>
</div>
```